# Is it possible to get a list of all files with iOS Google Drive drive.file permission?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

I was using drive.readonly permission in Google Drive, but suddenly it asked me to use drive.file permission.

As far as I understand, drive.file permission only applies to files uploaded by the app or files permitted by the user.
In fact, I was able to import the list with drive.readonly permission, but when I changed it to drive.file permission, I couldn't import any list.

Is there a way to get a list of all files and folders with drive.file permissions, or to get and browse a list of files and folders with a specific extension or mimetype?